# Installing spyder for python3 on mac

Tags: python, macos, spyder

I am very frustrated. It seems I don't understand a very basic concept of this installing and can't find an answer.

As the title says I want to install spyder for python3 on my mac. Since I couldn't find any easy installation just by clicking some where.

On mac python 2.7 is preinstalled and I already installed python3 which was pretty easy.

So I started by installing `pip` by typing `sudo easy_install pip` in the command line. Then I followed the introduction of [this site](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) which basically says to type `pip install -U spyder` which led to an error at the end. I realized that I have to use `pip3` because I have two python versions. Why is this nowhere mentioned?! Anyway this worked -- at least it didn't trigger an error. However, now I am confused where is the application? How can I use spyder now?

Any help is appreciated.

**edit**
As I changed into to folder bin suddenly the terminal responded to `spyder3`
But the result was

```
Nathanaels-iMac:bin nathanaelskrepek$ spyder3 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/spyder3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 144, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Comment: Since I got down votes it would be helpful to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*)

> So I started by installing pip by typing sudo easy_install pip in the command line.

Please avoid this route entirely. You should never, ever install things into your system Python (especially in macOS) because you can risk to break your system entirely. That's because Python is used by the operating system to run certain things, so it's better to leave it alone.

The simplest way to install Spyder in macOS is to [download Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and install it. Anaconda comes with all Spyder dependencies and also with the most important scientific Python libraries ready to be used.

Other options are Homebrew or MacPorts, but Anaconda is really the easiest one.

Comment: First of all thank you for your anwser.
In other words I may have done something very stupid and I maybe should do a new set up on my computer.
Can you explain me why my question is so bad that it got downvoted?

Comment: However I tried to install spyder again and the response was that everything is already done. My main confusion is even if I did everything right how do I start sypder? just typing spyder leads to -bash: spyder: command not found

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe you have an answer to this.

Comment: I think you forgot to install `pyqt5`, and that's why you're getting that error. For that, please run `pip install pyqt5`. About your other concerns: I really don't know why your question got downvoted. And no, you didn't do anything stupid. It's just that starting to use the Scientific Python stack when you're a beginner is not an easy task. I know we recommend to use pip or Anaconda to install Spyder in the page you referenced, so we're going to change our phrasing to *strongly* recommend Anaconda instead, and let users know that `pip` is for very knowledgeable users only.

Comment: okay but do I have to type `pip install pyqt5` or `pip3 install pyqt5`. As I already said I have both python versions on my mac but I want to use python3 und I am not entirely sure if `pip` and `pip3` are the same. I guess they are not.

Comment: You need to type `pip3`. In any case, there are no PyQt5 wheels for Python 2.

Comment: Glad to know! Hope you enjoy using Spyder :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why so many people advocate downloading Anaconda, because having another middleman seems to make installations more complicated further down the road.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Nathanael,

It sounds as though you've done the right thing, but you've done something else too.

```
pip3 install spyder # Installs Spyder for python 3
```

If you want to know where the Spyder app is, use the which command.

```
which spyder3 # This will give you the path to the application file.
```

If you want to use Spyder, enter spyder3 followed by the file you'd like to edit.

```
spyder3 myfilename.py # Opens (creates if needed) myfilename.py in Spyder.
```

Depending on how deep your trouble is, you may want to just re-install Spyder, or you will likley want to clean up your python3 install with something like Homebrew on your mac.

As you'll read on [Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder), Anaconda recently stopped financially supporting Spyder and they list some alternate installation methods which you may want to use if you're not going to use Anaconda or PIP.

Best of luck!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Although we're not funded by Anaconda anymore, we're not recommending any other installation method.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos, Good to know.  I corrected my answer.